# Delphi 2010, Master Detail - traverse detail for all records in master

Tags: delphi

Given master:
  Record
   A
   B

Detail
Choice  Record
  Y       A
  N       A
  Y       B
  N       B

using mastersource with index Record

If the cursor i on A (master), detail shows the two records linked to A (and so on).
This is ok.
If I leave the window, i want to check that all the records in detail A has Y and all then records B has Y in detail.
But it seems that I can check only the master/detail that has the focus in master.
I cannot find the B records in detail, if I am on the A master records.
Is there a way to traverse master programatic, starting on first records and get detail, then second record and get detail?

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is:

```
MasterTable.First;
while not MasterTable.Eof do
begin
  while not ChildTable.Eof do
  begin
    // Access child table data here. It will contain only the
    // rows related to the current row of MasterTable
    ChildTable.Next;
  end;
  MasterTable.Next;
end;
```

Comment: I code ChildTable.MasterSource and did not disable/enable controls as I often do. Then it seems to work. Thank you so much.

Comment: Works ok now. You put my mind in the right direction. Thank you.